# How to access Android/data folder on Android 13 without Root and PC?

Tags: android, directory, system, reverse-engineering, android-13

I'm able to see the folder of Android/data but I can't access it once I open the folder. I can access it if I connect my phone to pc. But I love to reverse-engineer to my phone so I need to find method to access it without root and Pc.

Comment: Where do you see the Android/data folder? And with which app are you opening it?

Comment: All folder from data is shown but if I click it will ask to give permission to access data but the data folder is not shown if I try to give access. I'm using mt manager app

Comment: i face even weirder issues, clicking new apps location takes me to a app which was given permission bfore. The new update totally crashed stuff. Guess gptta asl shopkeepers around to buy a a9 device nxt time.

Comment: by chance, Alhamdulilah, i found the solution. Just uninstall the updates of your phone's file manager.

Comment: It's still don't work @tanzin

Comment: Weird, try a good file manager then. I personally use mxexplorer.  JUST TO MAKW SURE, by device ifile manager i don't meant oem poor quality one but android systems file manager.

Comment: you are now stuck with it buddy, either root your phone or wait for another update which fix it(unlikely anytime soon). in my case, my file app was a bit older thus i just needed to uninstall the updates

Comment: That so unfortunate